# StackExchange.Redis throws an exception on Connect when Thrown CLR Exceptions is Enabled

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using `StackExchange.Redis`, which works wonderfully.  We use Redis as a fallback cache system and so the application doesn't actually require it to run.  When we're working locally with our project, we like to enable the `Thrown Common Language Runtime Exceptions` checkbox because we use some async methods and want the inner exceptions instead of `AggregateExeptions`, and catch errors a developer may have incorrectly swallowed.

When we start the project in VS with that option checked (and not starting the redis server instance), the `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect()` method throws a couple of nasty errors that you have to click through, etc to move forward.  We don't typically see this behavior with other third party libraries and since the library has a `ConnectionFailed` event, I'd have expected to see it simply trigger that method instead.

Any thoughts on how to prevent this from happening, or is this a bug, or am I just approaching this issue incorrectly?

**Update**

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Interesting - I'll have to enable the check box and see what breaks.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I've attached a screenshot for clarity. Hope it helps.